# Update part (order number) that is primary key in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have table:

```
book_id | part | name
1       | 1    | chap 1
1       | 2    | chap 2
1       | 3    | chap 3
1       | 4    | chap 4
```

Primary key is book_id and part.

How can delete part 2 and update order of parts to get:

```
book_id | part | name
1       | 1    | chap 1
1       | 2    | chap 3
1       | 3    | chap 4
```

I can do a transaction and firstly delete part 2, but how can i then update part column without getting duplicate primary key error?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you require `part` to have a continuous numerical sequence?  I would just leave it as-is and workaround the sequence.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not sure, maybe not, but what if i want to insert new part before 3, then i need to do the same i think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose a different approach. Instead of persisting the part number, persist the *order* of the parts:

```
CREATE TABLE book_part (
   book_id bigint NOT NULL,
   part_order real NOT NULL,
   name text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (book_id, part_order)
);
```

The first part that gets entered gets a `part_order` of 0.0. If you add a part at the beginning or the end, you just assign to `part_order` 1.0 less or more than the previous minimum or maximum. If you insert a part between two existing parts, you assign a `part_order` that is the arithmetic mean of the adjacent parts.

An example:

```
-- insert the first part

INSERT INTO book_part VALUES (1, 0.0, 'Introduction');

-- insert a part at the end

INSERT INTO book_part VALUES (1, 1.0, 'Getting started with PostgreSQL');

-- insert a part between the two existing parts

INSERT INTO book_part VALUES (1, 0.5, 'The history of PostgreSQL');

-- adding yet another part between two existing parts

INSERT INTO book_part VALUES (1, 0.25, 'An introductory example');
```

The actual part number is calculated when you query the table:

```
SELECT book_id,
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY book_id ORDER BY part_order) AS part,
       name
FROM book_part;
```

The beauty of that is that you don't need to update a lot of rows when you add or delete a part.

Comment: "*to insert a part between two existing parts, you assign a part_order that is the arithmetic mean of the adjacent parts.*" - doesn't this mean I can only do this around 32 times in a row (when always inserting before the same element), after which it exceeds the precision of the `real` type and ends up with multiple parts in the same location?

Comment: @Bergi Somewhat like that. You could use higher precision numbers if that doesn't suffice.

Comment: I was actually hoping for some clever algorithm that rearranges multiple items if the density becomes too irregular :-) But I guess that wouldn't be easy, and is probably not necessary in most use cases. Just some caveat one should be aware of to prevent surprises.

Comment: @Bergi Rearranging multiple items would defy the purpose. If you use `numeric`, you are practically unlimited.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most RDBMS, PostGreSQL does not support updating a primary key that might violate a preexisting value without having to use a deferred constraint.
In fact PostGreSQL execute the update row by row which conducts to find a "phantom" duplicate key, while other RDBMS that respects the standard uses a set based approach (MS SQL Server, Oracle, DB2...)

So you must use a deferred constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE book_part 
    ALTER CONSTRAINT ??? *PK constraint name* ??? DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
```

This is a severe limitations of PG... See "*5 – The hard way to udpates unique values*" in
http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/

Comment: "Severe" is a bit harsh.

Comment: Severe is the right word to describe a RDBMS that violates one of the fundamental rules of what a relational database should do, according to its founder Franck Edgar COdd's own terms. Rule 7 of Codd's 12 rules ...

Comment: I found the quotation in the SQL standard: Chapter 4.18.2 Checking of constraints: *Whenever an SQL-statement is executed, every enforced constraint whose mode is immediate is **checked, at a certain point after any changes to SQL-data and schemas** resulting from that execution have been effected, to see if it is satisfied.* (emphasis mine). So it is an actual shortcoming.

Comment: In which version and part of the SQL Standard doc does you extract come from ? There is many versions identified by years since SQL:1999 and the main parts of SQL is separate in may different doc titled Framework, Foundation, PSM...

Comment: But, anyway, the sentence is clear. Words have some meaning ! _Whenever an SQL-statement is executed, every enforced constraint whose mode is immediate is checked, at a certain point after any changes to SQL-data and schemas resulting from **that execution** have been effected, to see if it is satisfied._ 
The word execution mean that the quer(y/ies) have been executed. When a query that must modify many rows stop at the first row it is clear that, the execution have not been yet terminated ! The violation of rule 7 by PostGreSQL indicate clearly that it is not a real Relational BMS§

Comment: "Is not a real relational DBMS": you are obviously trolling, which makes me smile. Know, then, that it is very easy to get a unique or primary key constraint that behaves according to the standard in PostgreSQL: all you have to do is make it `DEFERRABLE` (not necessarily deferred). Such a constraint will be checked at the end of the statement, not after every row. The quotation is of course from part 2 of the standard.

Comment: In the book "The relational model for database Management" (V2, 1990) Codd (the RDBMS creator) defines many type of contraints and the rules to be applied for each type of constraints. Considering PK, Codd  says (p 247) that "Integrity constraints of type E are always of timing type TC". (TC means that constraint checking must be executed no later than the end of whatever relational request). PK are type E constraint (Entity Integrity). So a DEFERRED constraint cannot be applyed to an UPDATE for a PK.  PostGreSQL violate rule  7 of 12 codd's rules... So this confirme that PG is not a RDBMS!

Comment: Chris Date confirm that point to in his book "SQL and Relational Theory" (Oreilly 2009) page 172, chapter 8, p 172, § "Why a database constraint Checking Must Be Immediate". Remeber that Chris Date was the main colleague of Codd when creating RDBSM theory and practices (System R and SQL...)

Comment: You didn't listen. I said "deferrable", not "deferred". With your line of argumentation, there is no RDBMS in this world. Oracle, for example, does not implement `SERIALIZABLE` correctly. And Microsoft SQL server is so far from the standard that we don't even have to start discussing it.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server is one of the RDBMS closest to the SQL standard, while PostGreSQL increasingly laments it. The absence of MERGE, the lack of temporal tables, as well as the inability to use the READ UNCOMMITTED isolation level, the absence of CONTAINS predicate for fulltext search and also the SQL identifiers limited to 63 chars (ISO standard required 128), proves that PostGreSQL is very far from meeting the ISO SQL standard...

Comment: I was speaking about the conformances of RDBMS regarding the 12 codd's rules. Violating a Codd rule, confirme that the DBMS product is not Relational. This is the case with PostGreSQL that violate many codd's rules. Rule 7 as said, but also rule 11.