# Unique partial constraint in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table and want to update some of the rows like this:

```
CREATE TABLE abc(i INTEGER, deleted BOOLEAN);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myidx ON abc(i) WHERE NOT deleted;

INSERT INTO abc VALUES (4), (5);

UPDATE abc SET i = i - 1;
```

Which works ok because of the order in which the UPDATE is processing the rows, but when the UPDATE is attempted like this, it fails:

```
UPDATE abc SET i = i + 1;

ERROR:  23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myidx"
DETAIL:  Key (i)=(4) already exists.
SCHEMA NAME:  public
TABLE NAME:  abc
CONSTRAINT NAME:  myidx
LOCATION:  _bt_check_unique, nbtinsert.c:534
Time: 0.472 ms
```

The reason of the error is, in the middle of the update 2 rows would have had the value `i = 4`, even though at the end of the update all rows would have had unique values.

So I thought of changing the index into a deferred constraint, but according to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS), this is not possible as my index is partial (so it only enforces uniqueness on some rows):

> A uniqueness restriction covering only some rows cannot be written as a unique constraint, but it is possible to enforce such a restriction by creating a unique partial index.

The docs say to use partial indexes, but those can't be deferred, so I go back to the original problem.

So far my solution would be to set `i = NULL` whenever I mark `deleted = true` so it's not considered duplicated by my constraint anymore.

Is there a better solution to this? Maybe a way to make the UPDATE go always in the direction I want?

### Please note:

I cannot DELETE the row, that's why the `deleted` column is there. The actual delete is done after some human validation happens.

### Update:

The reason I'm bulk-updating that unique column is because this table contains a sequence that is used in the UI for sorting the records (the users drag and drop the records as they wish). And they can also delete them (so I shift the sequences of elements occurring after the one that was deleted).

The actual columns look more like this `(name TEXT, description TEXT, ..., sequence NUMBER)`.

That `sequence` row is what in the simplified case I called `i`. So say I have 3 records with `(name, sequence)`:

```
("Laptop", 1)
("Mobile", 2)
("Desktop", 3)
```

And I the user deletes the middle one, I want to end up with:

```
("Laptop", 1)
("Desktop", 2) // <--- updated here
```

Comment: There is no better way to do exactly what you want. But I wonder why you would bulk-update a unique column in many rows in a single statement. Can you describe the use case? Then perhaps we can find a different way to achieve the goal.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Added the explanation at the end of the question. Thanks. I'm starting to think if storing the row ids in an array column will be simpler.

Comment: Why would you need the values to be adjacent if their only purpose is ordering the entries in a UI view?

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you considered a solution along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67164998/6464308)?

Comment: @clamp I was doing so to facilitate adding a new record, so I didn't need to check which one was the higher sequence number (but the number of them would tell me what the sequence of the new row should be). But even if they are not consecutive, when drag&dropping them I would also need to do a batch update, for example when moving "Desktop" on top of "Mobile" I'll need to update "Mobile" and the rows that come after it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I had not considered making the `sequence` a real. That's also a possible solution for my case as I don't have so many rows that I would be concerned about running out of precision on the divisions. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Keeping the id values and storing the order in an array (especially when there are multiple sequence, not just a single global one) is what I went with in a similar solution. I also believe this makes batch updates easier (just drop all the ids in the array, as provided by the UI) and more efficient (needs to touch only a single row), however of course it means you cannot build an index any more that allows ranged searches (was not a problem in my scenario as each sequence would always be loaded completely anyway).