# Trigger on self-referenced table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have an `invoices` table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
    idinvoice SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    ,idclient INTEGER REFERENCES clients(idclient)
    -- other fields here
);
```

and an `invoiceitems` table :

```
CREATE TABLE invoiceitems (
    idinvoiceitem SERIAL PRIMARY  KEY
    ,idinvoice INTEGER REFERENCES invoices(idinvoice)
    ,amount NUMERIC(15,2)
    ,sortorder INTEGER DEFAULT 10
);
```

My problem is with the `sortorder` field : every time I insert or update an invoiceitem, I want the `sortorder`s of all items of the same invoice to be recalculated with a query like this :

```
WITH pre AS (
    SELECT idinvoiceitem,10*ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sortorder,idinvoiceitem) AS rownum
    FROM invoiceitems
    WHERE idinvoice=xx
    ORDER BY sortorder,idinvoiceitem
)
UPDATE invoiceitems di
SET sortorder=rownum
FROM pre p
WHERE p.idinvoiceitem=di.idinvoiceitem;
```

That way, every time a new item is added, it will be numbered 10+last item, and if I decide to change the sort order of the item by manually setting a value, all the `sortorder`s will be recalculated with a 10 increment :

```
id | sortorder
---+----------
 1 | 10
 2 | 20
 3 | 30
 4 | 40  ← I change this to 25
```

Then after the query, I will get :

```
id | sortorder
---+----------
 1 | 10
 2 | 20
 4 | 30
 3 | 40
```

I would like to have this in a trigger. The problem is that item #4 will be UPDATEd by the trigger (thus calling the trigger again) and I will get some kind of endless recursion.

Is there a way to do this ? For example, set some *semaphore* that would prevent the trigger from being called when the UPDATE occurs within the trigger itself ? Or maybe an explicit LOCK ?

(using PostgreSQL 11+)

Comment: The solution is perhaps *not* to persist the sort order...

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe What do you mean ? The user *wants* to enforce some sort order, hence my demand. Sorting by "insert timestamp" doesn't always work. What would you suggest ?

Comment: I would suggest generating the `sortorder` on the fly whenever you `SELECT` from the table.

Comment: I mean something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67164998/6464308).

Comment: I see. That was my first idea but it is not very user-friendly (what's the half of 0.125 ? Some people will have a hard time figuring out or will make errors). I could get around this in the interface but I like this simplistic approach. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: It is not the end user who has to make that calculation. Your code does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is to use `pg_trigger_depth()` function, which is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-info.html).

Then your trigger should look similar to this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON invoiceitem
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE your_procedure();
```

I'd recommend read some discussions about this approach ([1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163142/is-pg-trigger-depth-bad-to-use-for-preventing-trigger-cascading-recursion), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708562/prevent-recursive-trigger-in-postgresql)), but in general for not complicated systems this should be fine.